# Stacks, push and pops. Mars mips, example

Tags: mips

A letter means push into and an asterisk means pop out of an initially empty stack. Suppose the
following sequence of operation is performed. Draw the content of the stack for each step,
and then give the sequence of values popped out.
 V E R * Y E * * A S * * Y * * *

Now my classmates are getting their final answer to be this:

REYSAYEV    and I tried it and I am getting something different

Answer (score 2):

Why do it by hand when a machine can do it...

Try this Python code at https://repl.it/languages/python

```
instructions = "V E R * Y E * * A S * * Y * * *"

stack = []

for command in instructions.split():
    if command == '*':
        print "Output:", stack.pop()
    else:
        stack.append(command)

    print "Current stack: ", stack
```

Your classmates seem to be correct; example output:

```
Current stack:  ['V']
Current stack:  ['V', 'E']
Current stack:  ['V', 'E', 'R']
Output: R
Current stack:  ['V', 'E']
Current stack:  ['V', 'E', 'Y']
Current stack:  ['V', 'E', 'Y', 'E']
Output: E
Current stack:  ['V', 'E', 'Y']
Output: Y
Current stack:  ['V', 'E']
Current stack:  ['V', 'E', 'A']
Current stack:  ['V', 'E', 'A', 'S']
Output: S
Current stack:  ['V', 'E', 'A']
Output: A
Current stack:  ['V', 'E']
Current stack:  ['V', 'E', 'Y']
Output: Y
Current stack:  ['V', 'E']
Output: E
Current stack:  ['V']
Output: V
Current stack:  []
=> None
```

Comment: How would I write this in MIPS ?

Comment: I don't know; I assumed from the question that you were supposed to draw the stack by hand and this was more of an "work through the steps of what a stack does" question than a MIPS programming question.

Comment: Wow, okay now I am starting to get some intuition here. For the first one, you are taking out R so you have room for EY correct?

Comment: Thank you for this, this is starting to make more sense!

Comment: Another question for this: Current stack:  ['V', 'E', 'A']    why wouldn't it be  ['V', 'E', 'A', 'Y'] ?

Comment: It takes out R because the instruction is R *  (put R on the stack, then take the last stack item off). That's how it gets E Y next to each other, yes. I don't really get your other question; it wouldn't be V E A Y because two pop instructions took the E and the Y off. If you think the Y should stay then it would have to be V E Y A because you can only put things on the end, the A couldn't appear in the middle, before something else.

Answer (score 1):

What do you get? Here's work through:

```
Stack: VER
Operation: POP
Resultant Stack: VE
Pops: R

Stack: VE
Operation: PUSH Y
Resultant Stack: VEY
Pops: R

Stack: VEY
Operation: PUSH E
Resultant Stack: VEYE
Pops: R

Stack: VEYE
Operation: POP
Resultant Stack: VEY
Pops: RE

Stack: VEY
Operation: POP
Resultant Stack: VE
Pops: REY
```

and so on.

Comment: I get something like this REYSAEVY

Comment: Which why are you popping R?

Comment: I'm popping R because a * follows it

Comment: Your answer is so close, I suggest you try it from scratch. Maybe you just made a mistake